# Questions about parameter estimation for the Cauchy Distribution.

Tags: probability, statistics

$X_{1} ... X_{n}$ are i.i.d.  according to the Cauchy distribution centered at θ. The the density function is given by:

$\frac{1}{\pi} \cdot\frac{1}{[1 + (x-\theta)^2]}$

and the cdf is given by:

$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{\pi}arctan(x - \theta)$

Find the estimator of $\theta$. Using a concept similar to the method of moments, $\hat p_{n}$ denotes the proportion of negative observations which is close to its expected value of $F_{\theta}(0)$. Demonstrate that the estimator is consistent, and find the limiting distribution.

Couple questions here though:

1. For determining the estimator we set $\hat p_{n}$ equal to its expected value of $F_{\theta}(0)$ and solve for theta, correct? Here I obtained tan($\frac{\pi}{2} - \pi\hat p)$ = $\hat \theta$
2. How do we demonstrate the consistency of the estimator though? Can we argue that $X_1,\ldots,X_n\stackrel{iid}{\sim}\mathrm{Ber}(p)$ because p is a proportion of negative observations and there can only be two outcomes. Thus $\hat p_{n}$ = $\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i}{n}$ which means it converges to p using the weak law of large numbers? And because $\hat p_n$ converges to p, $\hat \theta$ must converge to $\theta$ as well due to the continuous mapping theorem?
3. I believe we can find the asymptotic distribution using the delta method. Is this correct as well?

Thanks, wondering here if I am on the right track. I don't know if I am off base here, to be honest.

Comment: You cannot say $X_1,\ldots,X_n\stackrel{iid}{\sim}\mathrm{Ber}(p)$ or $\hat{p}_n=\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i}{n}$ since the $X_i$ are the original observations; you need some other random variable to represent $\mathbb I_{X_i < 0}$

Comment: Oh right. Mistake on my end there. Couldn't p be the parameter for the indicator function which is a bernoulli random variable?

Comment: Apart from that comment, I would have thought your approach to 1 and 2 look reasonable.  For 3, I would guess if you use the delta method, you might want to use the normal approximation to the binomial at some stage

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

See the estimation section of [Wikipedia on Cauchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution#Estimation_of_parameters).

For the center, the sample median works, but the 38% trimmed mean is said to have slightly smaller variability.

Simulation for the special case of Student's t distribution with degrees of freedom $\nu=1$ and samples of size $n=100.$

[Note that the conditions of the [CLT for
medians](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/487518/clt-for-medians-for-distributions-without-means) are met, but conditions of the CLT for means are not.]

```
set.seed(111)
h = replicate(10^5, median(rt(100,1)))
summary(h);  sd(h)

      Min.    1st Qu.     Median       Mean    3rd Qu.       Max. 
-0.7395925 -0.1059586  0.0005111 -0.0000415  0.1050140  0.7057973 
[1] 0.1585002


a.38 = replicate(10^5, mean(rt(100,1),trim=.38))
summary(a.38);  sd(a.38)

      Min.    1st Qu.     Median       Mean     3rd Qu.       Max. 
-0.7270404 -0.1025867 -0.0009389 -0.0006116  0.1006515  0.7054522 
 [1] 0.1530064  # slightly smaller SD
```